# AWS Cognito Required Fields iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to hook up my iOS app to my AWS Backend via Cognito. I am a bit confused because I choose certain attributes that are required for sign-ups such as `Birthdate` and `Name`. Although once I followed directions to use the `AWSAuthUI` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html). The default UI appears as shown here:

[image: shows SOME of the required fields]

and then when one tries to sign up this error message comes up:

[image: error message]

which makes sense because the user did not input the other required fields as established by my User Pool, but how can I give the user the opportunity to submit their birthday if I'm using the `AWSAuthUI`

Comment: Available Fixes:
1. Add the required fields using the AWSAuthUI (which I can't find any information on) 
2. Create my own UI (which I have done), but then I couldn't find a way to hook it up to Cognito. It seems like I need to do all my own authentication, if I go this route (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the AWSAuthUI but you could do this easily with the User Pools sdk. Check out the [sample project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift) if you havent already seen it. In your case youll want to append birthday and name to the User attributes like the amazon team did with [their attributes in the sign up method](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift/CognitoYourUserPoolsSample/SignUpViewController.swift). Im not sure what you mean by "do all my own authentication"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per a comment, I'd like to answer my own question. It doesn't seem like there are any changes you can make to the `AWSAuthUI` other than small cosmetic changes. The best bet is to set up the UI yourself. The AWS team has set up a GitHub project that has an example of setting it up [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift). The relevant heading for Cognito User Pools is under, `CognitoYourUserPools-Sample`. They have options in both Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: Hi! I am facing a similar problem right now. Did you find a good solution? FYI: this is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616931/changing-cognito-user-pool-aws-amplify-leading-to-signup-issue/56617228#56617228