# Changing Cognito-User-Pool/AWS-Amplify; leading to SignUp issue

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am, handling some SignUp/SignIn process within an iOS app, using AWS-Amplify (and Cognito).

It was working fine, but then I decided to require a few more information when signing up.
Namely: name, given_name, family_name.

Here is the function called to authenticate:

```
func showSignIn() {
    AWSAuthUIViewController
        .presentViewController(with: self.navigationController!,
                               configuration: nil,
                               completionHandler: {
                                (provider: AWSSignInProvider, error: Error?) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    print("Error occurred: \(String(describing: error))")
                                } else {
                                    print("Identity provider: \(provider.identityProviderName)")
                                }
        })
}
```

After I did the necessary manipulations (using amplify-cli) to remove the old user pool and make a new one. I recompiled my iOS app and launched it.

This was OK, but now when I want to sign up a user I get this message:

[image]

The message content is not surprising, since now I require the indicated fields.
But the problem is that I don't see any space in the UI where to input those new fields.

Did I forget to do something so that the UI could be updated adequately?
Or am I suppose to do something (to update the UI by hand) by modifying the function above? If YES, what is the way to make the change?

These are my first steps with amplify, I may well be making some basic mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only using AWS Amplify with JavaScript, but in JS you do need to update the UI manually.

Here is the JS code and how I have to call it manually, maybe this helps.

```
handleSignUpPressed = async ({
  emailAddress = '',
  firstName = '',
  lastName = '',
  password = '',
  phoneNumber = '',
  wantsToImproveApp = true,
} = {}) => {
  if (emailAddress && firstName && lastName && password && phoneNumber) {
    try {
      const res = await Auth.signUp({
        username: emailAddress,
        password,
        attributes: {
          email: emailAddress,
          name: firstName,
          family_name: lastName,
          phone_number: phoneNumber,
        },
      });
      console.log('success', res);
      this.props.navigation.push('VerificationScreen', {
        username: res.username,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: That's likely to be true on iOS as well. I seems like there is some class called AWSAuthUIConfiguration which I should be able to use. But I don't think I can make much use of your code, at least this in my current impression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWSMobileClient to show the drop-in Auth https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#user-attributes which is using AWSAuthUIViewController underneath the covers.

I didn't see a way to customize it with SignInUIOptions for your use case. There is also an existing RFC to improve the usability of AWSMobileClient and the drop-in UI: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1158

If you roll your own sign-up/sign-in flow, you can then pass in user attributes to `AWSMobileClient.signUp`: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#user-attributes